# How do I use Perl to run a macro in an **already open** Excel workbook

Tags: perl, ole, excel

I would like to use Perl to run a macro in an **already open** Excel workbook.

The following code works if I just want to open a workbook and run a macro:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe    
use strict;
use Win32::OLE;

my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application') or die;
$Excel->Workbooks->open('M:\Programs\MyExcelFile.xls');
$Excel->run('Book1!ChartData');
$Excel->quit;
```

But how do I operate on an **open** workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetActiveObject`. From [the docs](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/lib/Win32/OLE.html#examples):

```
Here is a simple Microsoft Excel application.

        use Win32::OLE;

        # use existing instance if Excel is already running
        eval {$ex = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')};
        die "Excel not installed" if $@;
        unless (defined $ex) {
            $ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
                    or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
        }
```